# Flask, как сделать пагинацию страниц?

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

Подскажите как сделать пагинацию страниц на Flask ? Откуда начинать копать ? Если можно подскажите механизм(что нужно для этого, шаги и т.д).

Comment: `paginate()` встроено в Flask-SQLAlchemy. Чтобы узнать как работает (механизм), можно посмотреть на исходный код.

Comment: Вот еще - https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/

Answer (score 1):

Установака : `pip install -U flask-paginate`

Вью:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    page = request.args.get('page', type=int, default=1)

    users = User.find(...)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=users.count(), search=search, record_name='users')
    return render_template('users/index.html',
                           users=users,
                           pagination=pagination,
                           )
```

темплейт:

```
{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}
```