# Как реализовать постраничный вывод базы данных без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Есть файл table.html, в котором через цикл выводится база данных в виде таблицы, который в свою очередь включен в другой html файл:

```
<table id="users">
{% include "table.html" %}
</table>
<button id=backward>Предыдущая</button>
<button id="forward">Следующая</button>
```

Как можно реализовать на Python(фреймворк - Flask) постраничную навигацию используя AJAX, отображая, допустим, по 10 записей?

Comment: Абсолютно так же, как и без AJAX, только со стороны фласка отдавать нужный кусок страницы вместо всей страницы (обернуть в json по вкусу), а на стороне браузера скачивать этот кусок с помощью какого-нибудь XMLHttpRequest и пихать на страницу вместо старого куска

Comment: На фронте делать ajax-запросы с указанием окна выборки, а на бэке выбирать и отдавать данные попадающие в это окно. С чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Flask, как сделать пагинацию страниц?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649602/23044)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю как передать переменную с сервера в скрипт. Имеется такой запрос: 
    `rows = c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 10 OFFSET {x}')`
Я могу посредством простых ссылок изменить переменную x, чтобы отобразить следующую часть таблицы, но тогда перезагружается вся страница. Это не то что мне нужно